# Windows7 ApacheDS Installation - Does it also install Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, windows-7, telnet, cas, apacheds

I'm trying to setup CAS and I just recently downloaded and installed ApacheDS on Windows 7.

Here's a link to the instructions I'm following:
https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/CAS+on+Windows+Quick+Setup+Guide

1. The instructions for CAS tell me to use the telnet console, and type the following: open localhost 10389.  This is telling me it's failing to connect.
2. Furthermore, the CAS installation is asking me to star the Tomcat server.  Did this get installed along with ApacheDS?

Now I'm wondering if the two issues are related. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Both issues are not related : CAS server runs in Tomcat, ApacheDS runs on its own. First test with telnet console is to check if ApacheDS is up and running, the rest of the configuration is for CAS server and its own configuration to use ApacheDS.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I tried telnet'ing to apache using my example in #1 above, but it did not connect.  Is there something I need to do after the installation?